# Would like my students to watch movie that links to external html for test

Tags: flash

I'm new to Flash so please bear with me.  I would like my students to watch a flash movie and at the end of the movie a link would appear directing them to an external html page to take the test.  How do I code the movies to have the link appear at the end.  If it's AS, what is the necessary code?  The movies are too large to have in the timeline.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

the `VideoEvent.COMPLETE` should do the trick

something like this...

```
import fl.video.*;

// Video component instance name
var flvControl:FLVPlayback = display;
var flvSource:String = "Call_to_Action.flv";

// Loop the video when it completes
function completeHandler(event:VideoEvent):void
{
   // DISPLAY LINK HERE, LIKELY USING addChild
}
flvControl.addEventListener(VideoEvent.COMPLETE, completeHandler);

// Set video
flvControl.source = flvSource;
```

taken from http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/flvplayback_programming.html

Comment: I keep getting ...access of possibly undefined property COMPLETE through a reference with a static type class" error message after putting in this code.  What I am not seeing here.  Also can you explain the addchild